# Facebook Graph API: Get events by creator

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

How can I get the events from a creator (user or page) without FQL?
When I enter the ID's below I get a response but when I enter '328438627327927/events' in the graph explorer I get an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

ID public event = 1578821392346618
ID user (creator) = 328438627327927

Answer (score 0):

From what i've seen , since API ver 2.0, getting events by creator only works for pages, not users(unless they use your application and gave you permission). 
I guess it is a privacy matter.